# django suit проблема при сохранении новыого элемента из существующего

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

Имеется django-suit, модели товара. При нажатии на кнопку "сохранить как новый" появляется форма с теми же полями, однако невозможно удалить ненужные поля (изображения, характеристики) [image: админка]. Эти блоки подключаются инлайнами.

Comment: Так уберите в объявлении этих инлайнов ненужные поля. В чём проблема?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду сделать их необязательными? тут вышла подробность, если все заполнить и сохранить, то появляется сообщение "все сохранено и теперь можно редактировать данные"

Comment: Зависит от логики вашей программы. Можете сделать необязательными, можете вообще их не показывать.

Comment: проблема в самом suit, он делает точную копию модели и требует заполнения всех полей, после заполнения открывает для редактирования

Comment: django-suit - это просто тема для админки.